# How to debug Grails controller request timing issue

Tags: tomcat, grails

For a Grails app, there's a health check controller URL used by our load balancer to determine if the app is healthy or not.  If the health check endpoint considers the app healthy, it returns a 200 status code, and the app is put into the pool.

The main entry point into the app is a login controller URL.

When deploying the app, we found an issue where the health check URL was available for about a minute before the login page was actually available.  This is a problem because the load balancer puts the app in the pool before users can actually get to the login page.

Why would one controller endpoint be available so much sooner than another?

I attempted to fix the problem by adding a synchronous request to the login page from within the health check page as part of the health check, indicating health when the response to the login page within the health check is 200.  But even for this solution, the health check response is still available about 5 seconds before a direct call to the login page responds.  i.e. Calling one controller that makes a separate call to a 2nd controller works before a direct call to the 2nd controller works.

I'm not sure how to debug this timing issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'd start by looking at what is making that one controller take so long to start up.

Comment: What perplexes me about this problem is that the controller *is* available to one "client", but not available to another for a long time.